# TypeError: 'BitStream' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, bitstream

I am a newbie in the python world and I am getting an typing error that I am unsure of:

```
...File "/home/simon/python/piptroubleshoot/Main.py", line 15, in main
    hexToBase64(u'49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d')
  File "/home/simon/python/piptroubleshoot/Main.py", line 10, in hexToBase64
    base64.b64encode(hex(stream.read(4)))
TypeError: 'BitStream' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any ideas? This is the code the line in question is starred:

```
def hexToBase64(i: hex):
    stream = bitstring.BitStream(hex=i)
    while stream.length > 0:
        **base64.b64encode(hex(stream.read(4)))**

def main():
    """ Main program """
    print(u'49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d')
    hexToBase64(u'49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d')
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You give hex function a BitStream paramater instead of Integer. Also stream.length is not something decreasing to use in while loop.
But you can use below code to encodeb64.

```
def hexToBase64(i: hex):
    stream = bitstring.BitStream(hex=i)
    base64.b64encode((stream.read(stream.length).hex.encode()))
```

- stream.read(stream.length) -> reads all
- .hex -> converts to hex string
- .encode() -> makes it b'xxxx' format